# Why am I getting "yaml.scanner.ScannerError" when the syntax seems to be correct?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to make a docker-compose file for a CDC (change data capture) solution for which i need to run multiple docker containers my `DockerComposeLocal.yml` contains the following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
  zookeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:1.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.1
    ports: 
      - "9092:9092"
  kafka_connect:
    image: debezium/connect:1.1
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 
      - GROUP_ID=sde_group 
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=sde_storage_topic 
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=sde_offset_topic
```

But when I try to run it using this...

```
docker-compose -f DockerComposeLocal.yml up
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in ".\DockerComposeLocal.yml", line 2, column 9
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. Are there any tab characters in your original document?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, no there are no tab characters, I am using VsCode to edit and in vscode if there are any tabs they're usually represented as arrows, and there are no tabs just sapce characters according to this [article](http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2020/03/Visual-Studio-VS-Code-How-to-view-Tabs-tab-characters-in-a-file.html)

Were you able to run the containers without problems? @larsks

Comment: When I run `docker-compose up`, it starts pulling the images immediately and does not produce any errors about the YAML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping, what i realised that was going on was that when i runned the

```
docker-compose up
```

the terminal was on the wrong directory.